# Unable to detect page cache due to possible loopback request problem. Please verify that the loopback request test is passing

Tags: http-status-code-500

I'm really sorry, i need a help for my website: [[ilmusaku.com](https://ilmusaku.com)]

I have always received the following error warning on site health:

Unable to detect page cache due to possible loopback request problem. Please verify that the loopback request test is passing. Error: Internal Server Error (Code: http_500

Page cache enhances the speed and performance of your site by saving and serving static pages instead of calling for a page every time a user visits.

Page cache is detected by looking for an active page cache plugin as well as making three requests to the homepage and looking for one or more of the following HTTP client caching response headers:

`cache-control, expires, age, last-modified, etag, x-cache-enabled, x-cache-disabled, x-srcache-store-status, x-srcache-fetch-status, x-litespeed-cache, x-lsadc-cache, x-qc-cache.`

Can anyone help me ?

I try to reset .htaccess but not working.

Comment: You forgot to share the code involved, and the error message that your server has logged

Comment: Unable to detect page cache due to possible loopback request problem. Please verify that the loopback request test is passing. Error: Internal Server Error (Code: http_500

Comment: I think i found a problem, adsblock plugin gone wrong. Sorry anyone for your time.