# Unable to detect page cache due to possible loopback request problem

Tags: wordpress, caching, loopback

We have installed cache plugin(WP Rocket) on our website.

However, in my WordPress website health check, there is an error:

```
Unable to detect page cache due to possible loopback request problem. Please verify that the loopback request test is passing. Error: Not Found (Code: http_404)
```

Then I check the loopback test and it is passed:

```
Your site can perform loopback requests
```

I search online and find this post: [Unable to detect page cache due to possible loopback request problem. Please verify that the loopback request test is passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75683729/unable-to-detect-page-cache-due-to-possible-loopback-request-problem-please-ver)

But it does not provide solution as well.

So how to fix this issue? It seems that health check is trying to accessing some URLs to perform the tests but get 404 errors. So which URLs is it trying to access? Maybe I can check and fix them.

**Update**

The issue is fixed. The reason is that I do not set a homepage for the site, which cause the problem.